# Receive messages of all types with Spring Cloud @StreamListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, messaging, spring-cloud-stream

We are using Spring Cloud Stream.

I want to receive messages -- no matter the format -- with this method:

```
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
public void receiveMessage(String message) {
```

However, I do not receive messages that are of type JSON.

How can I enable `@StreamListener` to receive messages of all types?

Comment: I believe `Message<Object> message` should be possible. further reading: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream

Comment: Or `receiveMessage(byte[])`.